# Better Explanation for Sessions Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, session, refresh

I am trying to use sessions for the first time and would like to know abt that in a better and easy way.

I am creating a session variable using GUID and creating a folder with that GUID  and storing that value as shown below

```
 If Session("tempDir") Is Nothing Then
        Dim tempDir As String
        tempDir = Path.GetRandomFileName()
        tempDir = tempDir.Substring(0, tempDir.LastIndexOf("."))
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("Uploads/" & tempDir))
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("Downloads/" & tempDir))
        Session.Add("tempDir", tempDir)
        currentDirectory.Value = Session("tempDir").ToString
        CopySession.Text = currentDirectory.Value
    End If
```

This is the code for generating GUID:

```
 function randomString(length) {
            var chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');

            if (!length) {
                length = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            }

            var str = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                str += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
            }
            return str;
        }
```

I am using the below code to get that on page is postback but whenver I refreshes it deletes that value and gives me a NULL value.

```
If Page.IsPostBack Then
            If Session("tempDir") Is Nothing Then
                Dim tempDir As String
                tempDir = Path.GetRandomFileName()
                tempDir = tempDir.Substring(0, tempDir.LastIndexOf("."))
                IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("Uploads/" & tempDir))
                IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("Downloads/" & tempDir))
                Session.Add("tempDir", tempDir)
                currentDirectory.Value = Session("tempDir").ToString
                CopySession.Text = currentDirectory.Value

            End If
End If
```

How do I `retrieve` the `tempDir` value?Can anyone give me some detailed explanation regarding this as I am totally confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this 2 lines out of the IF

```
        currentDirectory.Value = Session("tempDir").ToString
        CopySession.Text = currentDirectory.Value
```

will be

```
If Page.IsPostBack Then
            If Session("tempDir") Is Nothing Then
                Dim tempDir As String
                tempDir = Path.GetRandomFileName()
                tempDir = tempDir.Substring(0, tempDir.LastIndexOf("."))
                IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("Uploads/" & tempDir))
                IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("Downloads/" & tempDir))
                Session.Add("tempDir", tempDir)
            End If

            currentDirectory.Value = Session("tempDir").ToString
            CopySession.Text = currentDirectory.Value
End If
```

What Is the different here, that if the session is not exist, then go and set it it. After the if the session for tempDir exist because ether you just set it, ether get it from previous or other call. I hope this give you what you wondering, or else tell me what you do not understand.

### Session

The session is a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) of values that is connected with each user for the time the session is active (eg for 20 minutes). As the user interacts with the site this data is follow this user and you can set them, read them or delete them using the session. 
When a page loads the session data read at the start, you can used them on page, and on page unload the session data saved back to session keeper.

Comment: @Aristos-Thanks for your explanation.And still I am in a bit confusion as not with your code but What happens is I have kept breakpoints and checked on page postback code it dosen't read the session again it's just loosing it.Do I need to add any global.aspx page for this?And add any web.config sections?

Comment: @Aristos-Sorry-I have added this code and twice and didn't change the other.Worked perfectly well!

Comment: @DotNetter If you use InProc session and not SQL session is very possible on every reload of your application to reset it.